# get number of months after subtracting current Y-m

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im having months in the below format

```
2012-01
2012-02
2012-03
2012-04
2012-05
2012-06
```

The months are stored in varchar (i wanted to store only the month). I would like to know how is it possible to subtract the current Y-m along with the months in the database and return the months?

```
Eg: (2012-11) - (2012-06) = 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the months, that'd be a number... why use varchar? int would be better suited.

But since it's varchar, just use string operations, instead of ugly math:

```
month = RIGHT(yourvalue, 2)
```

e.g.... `2012-11` -> `11`

Comment: Agreed, easiest option especially since its in MySQL

Comment: It is nice because it is easy but your solution can't handle year overflows.

Comment: Then don't store as varchars. you're in for a world of hurt. use native date-time values and use a fixed 'day' of 1 or something.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the help mate but i think its better save it as datetime to avoid complexities :)

Comment: I wouldn't plan on using this if you ever have months in different years. ie: 2013-12 and 2012-12

Comment: @Sammitch yep.. thats the problem there will be an issue when it comes to years.

Comment: `@months := LEFT(yourvalue, 4) * 12 + RIGHT(yourvalue, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

I guess that there already are solutions for date calculation out there. But for you simple task this might me overkill.

If you only want the result in month I suggest to convert you dates in months only.

```
$year   = substr($string,  0, 4);   // first four digits
$month  = substr($string, -2);      // last two digits
$months = $year * 12 + $month;
```

Then you can easily subtract two dates and the result will be the offset in months.

```
$offset = $months1 - $months2;
```

In your example this would compute the following.

```
$string1 = "2012-11";
$string2 = "2012-06";
$year1   = substr($string1,  0, 4); // 2012
$year2   = substr($string2,  0, 4); // 2012
$month1  = substr($string1, -2);    // 11
$month2  = substr($string2, -2);    // 06
$months1 = $year1 * 12 + $month1;   // 24155
$months2 = $year2 * 12 + $month2;   // 24150
$offset  = $months1 - $months2;     // 5
```

Here is a simple php function performing your task.

```
function months($string)
{
    if(strlen($string) < 6) return; // just to be sure
    return substr($string, 0, 4) * 12 + substr($string, -2);
}

function offset($minuend, $subtrahend)
{
    return months($minuend) - months($subtrahend);
}

echo offset("2012-11", "2012-06");  // output "5"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function getMonthCount($date) {
    $parts = explode('-', $date);
    return ($parts[0] * 12) + $parts[1];
}

$first  = '2012-11';
$second = '2012-06';
echo getMonthCount($first) - getMonthCount($second);
```